# Как замаппить List для сохранения сущностей

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, аннотации

Вообщем решил я освоить JPA в аннотациях и пока не очень получается.

Есть у меня класс GenericAd и Image. Image ссылается на GenericAd @ManyToOne, а в ответ на Image есть List @OneToMany. Такой фишкой я хочу сохранять в базу новый Image из GenericAd, то есть проставил List в GenericAd и при сохранении/изменении автоматом добавляются новые Image в БД. Такое удавалось делать с помощью xml. Но вот с JPA намучился, не получается.

Вот маппинг:

GenericAd:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class GenericAd {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(length = 6, nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Type(type="text")
    private String description;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String dateAdd;
    @Column
    private AdType adType;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumberAuthor;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String city;
    @Column
    private String region;
    @Column
    private String district;
    @Column
    private String price;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String adLink;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "adEntity", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Image> images;
```

Image:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(length = 6, nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private byte[] image;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "ad_id")
    private GenericAd adEntity;
```

Сохраняю данные через GenericAdDAO с помощью HibernateTemplate
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе я ожидаю сохраненную GenericAd(genericad) и Image(в таблицу image)
GenericAd сохраняется нормально, а Image нет, хотя debugger'ом проверял List < Image > в GenericAd не пуст перед сохранением.

Вот БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И image пусто!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Уточни, что хранится в базе при сохранении GenericAd и как должно быть? И если есть возможность, добавь код, которым сохраняешь GenericAd.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Перед сохранением попробуй присвоить ссылку в Image на GenericAd примерно так  (for(int i = 0; i <  genericAd.getImages().size(); i++){
        genericAd.getImages().setAdEntity(genericAd);
    }), ну и вопрос, сохраняется Image отдельно, без GenericAd?

Comment: посмотрел картинки, ты используешь метод save(), а надо использовать persist(), попробуй с этим методом

Comment: это гениально! Методом persist() все сохранилось! Если хотите поставьте в ответы, галочку поставлю) Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для правильной работы cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST с HibernateTemplate нужно использовать метод persist(), а не save()